# Finite union of measurable rectangles can be written as union of pairwise disjoint measurable rectangles?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have two measure spaces $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$.  $R \subseteq X \times Y$ is called a *measurable rectangle* if $R = A \times B$ with $A \in \Sigma$ and $B \in \tau$.

I have the following idea proved and at my disposal:  If $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are measurable rectangles, then $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ and $R_{1} \setminus R_{2}$ can both be written as finite unions of pairwise disjoint measurable rectangles.

The proof that $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ can be written as a finite union of pairwise disjoint rectangles is as follows:  $R_{1} \cup R_{2} = (R_{1} \setminus R_{2}) \cup (R_{1} \cap R_{2}) \cup (R_{2} \setminus R_{1})$.

**Can someone help me prove that $R_{1} \cup R_{2} \cup R_{3}$ can be written as a finite union of pairwise disjoint measurable rectangles?**  I tried and failed to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\cal R$ be the collection of sets that are expressible as the finite union of disjoint rectangles, and $\bar{\cal R}$ be the collection of sets that are expressible as the finite or countable disjoint union of rectangles. Obviously ${\cal R} \subset \bar{\cal R}$.

Suppose $R\in {\cal R}$ and $D$ is a rectangle. Then $R =\cup_{k=1}^n D_k$, where $D_k$ are pairwise disjoint rectangles. Then $D \cup D_k = 
D \cup (D_k \setminus D) $, and so $R = D \cup \left( \cup_{k=1}^n D_k \setminus D \right)$. You know that each $D_k \setminus D$ can be written as the union of pairwise disjoint rectangles, hence so can $R \cup D$.

It follows by induction that if $R_k \in {\cal R}$ then $\cup_{k=1}^n R_k \in {\cal R}$.

If $D_1, D_2$ are rectangles, then you know that $D_1 \setminus D_2 \in { \cal R}$. Suppose $R\in {\cal R}$ and $D$ is a rectangle, then $R =\cup_{k=1}^n D_k$, where $D_k$ are pairwise disjoint rectangles. Then
$R \setminus D = \cup_{k=1}^n \left(  D_k \setminus D \right)$, and so $R \setminus D \in {\cal R}$.
It follows by induction that if $R_1, R_2 \in {\cal R}$, then $R_1 \setminus R_2 \in {\cal R}$.

Also, if $R_k \in {\cal R}$, then since $\cup_{k=1}^n R_k \in {\cal R}$ for all $n$, we have 
$\cup_{k=1}^\infty R_k \in \bar{\cal R}$.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my question.  The whole reason I am confused is that I don't know how to prove that a finite union of measurable rectangles can be expressed as a union of pwd measurable rectangles.  I only know how to do it for a single union.  If $R_{1}$, $R_{2}$ are meas rectangles, then $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ can be written as $(R_{1} \setminus R_{2}) \cup (R_{1} \cap R_{2}) \cup (R_{2} \setminus R_{1})$, which is a finite union of pwd measurable rectangles.  Can you prove $R_{1} \cup R_{2} \cup R_{3}$ can be written as a union of pairwise disjoint measurable rectangles?

Comment: I added the outline of a proof that $R_1\cup R_2 \cup \cdots \cup R_n$ can be expressed as the union of pairwise disjoint rectangles. Basically you add one rectangle at a time.

Comment: I'm still really confused.  It would help me out a lot if we could explicitly write down the finite union of pairwise disjoint rectangles that $R_{1} \cup R_{2} \cup R_{3}$ breaks down into, just like we did for the $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ case.  Do you know how to write down the union of 3 of them explicitly as a union of pairwise disjoint ones?

Comment: By the way, aside from this case, your proof makes sense as to how it extends to the infinite union case.  But I am just having trouble extending from the union of 2 sets to the union of 3 sets.

Comment: It is clear that if $R$ is a finite union of pairwise disjoint sets and $D$ is a rectangle that you can write $R \cup D$ as a finite union of pairwise disjoint sets?

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  I will apply what you wrote to the case where we have a union of 3 of them.  We know $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ is expressible as a finite union of pairwise disjoint rectangles.  If we say $R_{1} \cup R_{2} = \bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{n} D_{k}$, where $\{ D_{k} \}_{k = 1}^{n}$ are pairwise disjoint, then $\{ D_{k} \setminus R_{3} \}_{k = 1}^{n}$ are pairwise disjoint, and hence $R_{3} \cup \bigcup \limits_{k = 1}^{n} (D_{k} \setminus R_{3})$ is a union of pairwise disjoint rectangles, which equals $R_{1} \cup R_{2} \cup R_{3}$.  If I didn't make any mistakes, then yes!

Comment: Well, you have given a perfectly good proof, but it is not what I have above (which adds one rectangle at a time).

Comment: I applied what you wrote to the case with only a union of 3, which aided my understanding.  Thank you for your excellent help!

Comment: Well, you are very welcome, albeit you did it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an indirect approach. If D is the algebra of finite disjoint unions and F is the algebra of finite unions, then D is contained in F, both contains rectangles and F is minimal with this property, so D=F.

Now the problem is to show that F and D specially are algebras. Insted of proving that D is close under finite unions, try yo prove that it is close under finite intersections.

This is problem 10.D un Bartle's book Measure Theory.